# Adding widgets outside main window in Qt Designer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

I am new to QtDesigner - in the main window when I am adding widgets, I can't add any more widgets off-screen (i.e where scrolling down would normally allow me to access and view).  There is probably a very simple answer to this but I can't find it anywhere.   Is the main window a fixed size that will not allow widgets to be added outside of the dimensions of the full screen? 
Thanks

Comment: You could explain me better, maybe with a diagram or image of what you want to obtain, I've already seen the same unclear question a few days ago.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, thanks for your response and apologies for my vague question. As I suspected, I was looking at the problem the wrong way. I managed to add a scroll area to the main window, then, by adjusting the layout, get the scroll area to utilise the whole window and allow me to scroll down to place/access widgets which otherwise would not have been visible.